# Maven multimodule library build

Tags: java, maven, maven-module

I'm developing library with Maven system, which is published in the Nexus repository.
In the nexus (and the maven build as well), the project produces the final `jar` named `<projectName>-<version>.jar` - this is exactly what I want.

Now, I decided to split the library into maven modules and therefore top level `pom.xml` have `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. The build also do not produce final `<projectName>-<version>.jar`, instead it produces `<moduleName>-<version>.jar` for each module.

What I want to achieve is to have the project split into modules and be able to produce final `<projectName>-<version>.jar` containing defined modules. Is this possible?
Is it possible to solve this issue migrating to the Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you decided to split the library into multi modules it means that you decided to build them independently. So it's expected that each module creates it's own `<moduleName>-<version>.jar`.

Now when you use the created modules as `dependencies` for the bigger module with scope of `compile` maven would automatically add them to `lib` of the project.

So in your case you don't need to change packaging to `pom` and just add the modules as dependency in the `pom.xml` file and let maven to create the final jar for you.

Also if you want use `pom` packaging there is a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032721/use-pom-packaging-maven-project-as-dependency) which might help you.